# bootstrap table is not responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I have a table which fills data from database. Though i had use the bootstrap when i kept on decreasing the width of the browser, from one point onward the table is going outside the container. How can i make this responsive ? Following are the attached images

```
 <table  class="table table-responsive table-bordered">


            <tr>
                <th>Spare Id</th>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Warranty</th>
                {{--<th>Description</th>--}}
                <th>Spare Image</th>

                <th>


                    <input   type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Spare">
                </th>


            </tr>
            <tbody id="tableModel">
            <?php
            foreach($spares as $spare){

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td ><?php echo $spare->id;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $spare->partNumber;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $spare->quantity;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo 'Rs.'. $spare->price;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $spare->warranty;?></td>


                <td><?php echo '<img  class="img-responsive"  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $spare->image ).'"/>';?></td>
                <td>

                    <a class=" btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit" onclick="EditBrand('<?php echo $brand->brandName;?>','<?php echo $brand->id;?>')" >Edit </a>

                    <a onclick="DeleteBrand(<?php echo $brand->id;?>)" style="" class=" btn btn-danger btn-sm"  >Delete </a>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <?php }?>
            </tbody>


        </table>
```

[image: This is when the normal width]

[image: When i kept on decreasing the size]

Comment: A picture is nice but we'll need to see your code. See [mcve]

Comment: your table probably has a fixed or minimum width

Comment: no there is no style called min width

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you use bootstrap. Wrap your table in a `div` with `table-responsive` class.

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
       ...
    </table>
 </div>
```

That should work if bootstrap is correctly integrated. Please show your code. Many more people would help you.

You can find this specific information here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Answer (score 5):

I have worked a lot n this issue and found a good solution for this bootstrap table responsiveness issue. Just use the CSS below:

```
.table{
   display: block !important;
   overflow-x: auto !important;
   width: 100% !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line, that will solve your problem.

`<div class='table-responsive'>`
 `<div style="overflow-x:auto;">`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you checked you have inserted enough data in table. Sometimes there is just not enough data to trigger 'table-responsive' property.